# How can I use machine learning to convert orientation sensor data into movement events?

Tags: python, machine-learning, sensors

I built a device based on a microcontroller with some sensors attached to it, one of them is an orientation sensor that currently delivers information about pitch, yaw, roll and acceleration for x,y,z. I would like to be able to detect movement "events" when the device is well... moved around.

For example I would like to detect a "repositioned" event which basically would consist of series of other events - "up" (picked up), "move" (moved in air to some other point), "down" (device put back down).

Since I am just starting to figure out how to make it possible I would like to ask if I am getting the right ideas or wasting my time.

My idea is currently that I use the data I probed to create a dataset and try to use machine learning to detect if each element belongs to one of the events I am trying to detect. So basically I took the device and first rotated it on table a few times, then picked it up several times, then moved it in the air and finally put it down several times. This generated a set of data that has a structure like that:

```
yaw,pitch,roll,accelx,accely,accelz,state
-140,178,178,17,-163,-495,stand
110,-176,-166,-212,-97,-389,down
118,-177,178,123,16,-146,up
166,-174,-171,-375,-145,-929,up
157,-178,178,4,-61,-259,down
108,177,-177,-55,76,-516,move
152,178,-179,35,98,-479,stand
175,177,-178,-30,-168,-668,move
100,177,178,-42,26,-447,stand
-14,177,179,42,-57,-491,stand
-155,177,179,28,-57,-469,stand
92,-173,-169,347,-373,-305,down

[...]
```

the last "state" column is added by me - I added this after each test movement type and then shuffled the rows.

I got about 450 records this way and the idea is to use the machine learning to predict the "state" column for each record coming from the running device, then I could queue up the outcomes and if in some short period the "up" events are majority I can take it the device is being picked up.

Maybe instead of using each reading as a data row I should rather take the last 10 readings (lets say) and try to predict what happens per column - i.e. if I know last 10 yaw readings were the changes during I was moving the device up I should rather use this data - so 10 readings from each of the 6 columns is processed as row and then I have 6 results - again the ratio of result types may make it possible to detect the "movement" event that happened during these 10 readings.

I am currently about 30% into an online ML course and enjoying it but I'd really like to hear some comments from more experienced people.

Are my ideas a reasonable solution or am I totally failing to understand how I can use ML? If so, what resources shall I use to get myself started?

Answer (score 0):

Your idea to regroup the reading seems interesting. But it all depends on how often you get a record and how you plan on grouping them.

If you get a record every 10-100ms, it could be a good idea to group them since it will help to have more accurate data reducing noise. You could take the mean of each column to get rid of that noise and help your classifier to better classify your different states.

Otherwise if you have a record every second, I think it's a bad idea to regroup the records since you will most certainely mix several actions together.

The best way would be to try out both ways if you have the time ^^